A problem occurred configuring project ':capacitor-android'
A problem occurred configuring project ':capacitor-android'.
> Could not read build file '/Users/Umishs4/Documents/react-session/react-capacitor/node_modules/@capacitor/android/capacitor/build.gradle' as it does not exist.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

I tried this url and tried to setup
https://capacitorjs.com/solution/react
Followed all steps,
Then ran below commands
npm run build
npx cap add android
npx cap sync
npx cap open android
Project opened in Android Studio. But in sync it is giving error.

